# Dependency Injection of optional user components

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I've been trying to build my own PHP MVC framework purely as an educational exercise and I wanted some input on how best to deal/design the framework to support dependency injection of optional user components.

For example, there is a 'core' framework config object and then, under the application folder, the user could specify their own application config file/object should they require it.

Rather than create the core config object within a specific controller, I inject the core config object into the controller as this will make testing easier (and follows the principle of dependency injection).

This is all well and good and makes sense, but what happens with the application config object? A user could use the framework and NEVER need an application specific config obejct/file and so injecting an application specific config object for every controller seems inefficient and a waste (on resources).

**So basically what I'm asking is how can I support dependency injection of components that the user may or may not need?**

Please keep in mind that I've very new to the idea of dependency injection and TDD, so I'm guessing there's a very trivial solution to the question above, but I haven't stumbled across it yet from all the articles I've read.

I thought I found the answer in this http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/21/where-have-all-the-singletons-gone/ Misko Hevery article, but I think factories do not solve the problem of optional user components.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what bother you is the fact of injecting objects that may not end up being used.

This can be solved by using **lazy-injection**, which is the injection of an empty **proxy object** that will load the "real" object only when it is used.

[PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/) supports it for example:

```
class Class1 {
    /**
     * @Inject(lazy=true)
     * @var Class2
     */
     private $class2;
```